# How to get html page content before rendered in CEFSharp

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have developed a Chromium Enabled Framework Web browser and i want to get the html page content before it render how it can be possible.

Comment: It's called a responsefilter, examples in the source, doco in the general usage guide